# .htaccess folder/subdomain rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am going through a strange behaviour of .htaccess.

I am writing a rule of .htaccess to convert the below url :

I want to convert the following URL (where `site` is variable.)

```
www.xyz.com/domain/site
```

to

```
site.xyz.com/
```

Note that `/site` is generated at runtime. (Created by user)

But my rule is not working.

**MY CODE**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !www.xyz.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-]+).xyz.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) nono.html?sm=%2 [NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working". You have an erroneous _space_ the CondPattern of the 2nd RewriteRule which will "break" the server, so is this just a typo in the question? Do you have a wildcard subdomain configured on your server, so these subdomains do resolve?

Comment: yes wildcard is configured i just need to redirect to subdomain..@w3dk

Comment: @w3dk i need need a htaccess rule to just hit the dynamic subdomain url,even after removing space it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your current rule appears to "sort of" do the opposite of what you are asking in the question, but with an extra twist. ie. a URL for the form `site.xyz.com/something` would be internally rewritten to `site.xyz.com/nono.html?sm=site`. (?)

To *redirect* `www.xyz.com/domain/site` to `site.xyz.com/`, as you've stated, then you could do something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(xyz\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^domain/([^/]+)$ http://$1.%1/ [R=302,L]
```

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to `301` (permanent) when you are sure this is working OK. Or test with browser caching disabled. (`301` redirects are otherwise cached by the browser, so can make testing problematic.)

Answer (score 0):

I got your issue.

your re-write rule is just opposite..

use this for your exact problem

and it will work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   ^(www\.)?xyz.com/domain/(.+)$(.*)
RewriteRule  (.*)  https://$1.xyz.com/  [L]
```